# Write and update XML file

Tags: php, xml

Is anybody familiar with a way in which I can update a xml file and write this data to it under the user tag?

I can create a new user but I cannot create multiple knew users.

If I could use the strstr() function to search the file for the xml tag `<Users>` that would be great. Is it possible to do with a xml file?

```
<?php
$servername ='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','ftpaccounts');

//create variales and check if form is submitted
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$passwordVerified = $_POST['passwordVerified'];
$directory = $_POST['directory'];


//ifstatement
if(isset($_POST['clicked'])) {
  $path = $directory;
  mkdir($path,0777,true);

  ///write to xml file
  $xml ='FileZilla Server/FileZilla Server.xml';

  $handler = fopen($xml,'w');
  $NewUserInsertedData = fwrite($handler,'<User Name="'.$login.'">
    <Option Name="Pass">B7B5349BC807B2C385478AA02C2ADDCEA37F3330994D15457C8CB5ED378EF9C7D0E64D5366048AEFEF8F2424662B25A1025D863ACB5F39093BA04091BE510412</Option>
    <Option Name="Salt">)W5@&apos;jgXQ5^&amp;p2F$Wa2V2F4~RG^Ox9.J24H(:LB)i;M[BbQ8&lt;m,J52@Jt$!8Ms/.</Option>
    <Option Name="Group"></Option>
    <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
    <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
    <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
    <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
    <IpFilter>
      <Disallowed />
      <Allowed />
    </IpFilter>
    <Permissions>
      <Permission Dir="C:\Users\greatness\Desktop\New folder">
        <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
        <Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>
        <Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
        <Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
        <Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
        <Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
        <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
        <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
        <Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>
        <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
      </Permission>
    </Permissions>
    <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
      <Download />
      <Upload />
    </SpeedLimits>
  </User>
');
}
fclose($handler);
system('"FileZilla Server/FileZilla server.exe' . '"' . '/reload-config');
////////////////////////////////////////

//query DataBase
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (login,password,password_check,sign_up_date) VALUES ('$login','$password','$passwordVerified','$directory');";

$run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
///
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: thanks for the map. Much needed and  appreciated.

Comment: Where is the *multiple* coming from? I see only one set of `$_POST` variables. Be sure to parameterize your append query especially if values are from user input.

Comment: thank you ,I will take care of security. My concern now is just on the foundation. The multiple is being used in reference to my goal.